# Trouble importing sklearn while using joblib

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, joblib

I have a prediction program that predicts binary classifications using classifiers. When I try to run the program I get the same issues over and over again:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\predict.py", line 252, in main
    clf = joblib.load('classifier.pkl')
  File "C:\Users\rando\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 585, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
  File "C:\Users\rando\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 504, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\pickle.py", line 1212, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\pickle.py", line 1537, in load_stack_global
    self.append(self.find_class(module, name))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\pickle.py", line 1579, in find_class
    __import__(module, level=0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

I have tried the following:

- pip3 install scikit-learn scipy matplotlib numpy
- pip3 uninstall joblib && pip3 install joblib sklearn
- pip3 uninstall sklearn joblib && pip3 install joblib==1.0.1

It appears that sklearn is being imported somewhere however I don't ever import it?

Comment: have your tried importing `sklearn`?  What happens?

Comment: Also, it looks like the error may not be originating in `joblib`: it's on account of `pickle`ing issues.  IIRC `pickle` doesn't always get all of the dependencies you need when you create a pickle

Comment: Yeah, it says module doesn't exist regardless of installation: `python3 -m pip install sklearn && python3 -c 'import sklearn'
Requirement already satisfied: sklearn in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.0.post1)

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3 -> 22.3.1
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
`

Comment: This last comment is your real question, then.  `joblib` is a red herring, and will throw off potential answerers.  You moght want to revise.

Comment: @Him "IIRC pickle doesn't always get all of the dependencies you need when you create a pickle" the only thing that's pickled is the classification files, they're unpickled in the beginning of the program so im not sure what you mean?

Comment: They're unpickled at the beginning, but when are they pickled?  At time of pickling, there may have been references that did not get pickled as well.  Pickling doesn't get external stuff, I think, so when unpickling, you have to have all of the references that the pickle needs.

Comment: Although, it looks like this is a red herring as well, and you just can't import sklearn.  That is the question you should be asking.

Comment: @user12969777 `joblib` basically just uses multiprocessing, which requires pickling data to share across the various processes. You can see in the error message yourself that the picking error is being raised from `joblib`. In any case, as already stated, joblib does not seem to be the issue, since you can recreate this with just trying to `import sklearn`

Comment: okay well let me try something and i'll revise the questions, thank you

Comment: @Him I'll revise the question, if you want to put your comment as the answer I'll accept it. Thank you

Comment: @user12969777 there is almost certainly 10 existing questions related to unpickled dependencies.  If this convo was helpful, please find a good one and mark your question as a duplicate.